# How to quickly delete entries from parcellite history

Tags: clipboard, clipboard-manager

Is it possible to quickly delete an element from the [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/?page_id=31) history?

`<Ctrl><Alt>H` opens the history, and I can arrow down to certain entries, but `Del` does not delete them.

This 
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&p=1306206
mentions `<Alt>-c` as deleting, but that also doesn't work. Furthermore, I can't find any documentation for such functionality.

I am running Parcellite svn, GTK 2.24.32 on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible:

http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/?page_id=31

Answer (score 2):

As a quick update, this is now possible [as explained here](https://www.mankier.com/1/parcellite) by holding `ctrl`, right-clicking the entries you want to delete (which causes them to appear with the strikethrough font effect), releasing `ctrl`, then hitting `enter`.  The version of Parcellite I have installed is 1.2.1-3+build1.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you want to clear your entire history, or most of it, go into `Preferences` and set `items in history` to a lower number, such as 10 or 1, and then click "OK". Go back into `Preferences` and set `items in history` back to what it was before the change. Now you only have to delete a few entries manually by using `ctrl` + `right click` and then pressing `enter`.

If you want to keep some of the items, move them to persistent history first, and then perform the steps the above.